# How to add users programmatically to TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to add users programmatically to a Team Project. What I found out to be the solution was this:

```
IGroupSecurityService gss = (IGroupSecurityService)objTFS.GetService(typeof(IGroupSecurityService));
Identity identity = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "Group name", QueryMembership.None);
gss.AddMemberToApplicationGroup(groupProject.Sid, member.Sid);
```

But this only work for  groups/users known to TFS.

I want to add a Windows account to TFS

For example:

Windows account name: TestTFS

Password:123456

Then add the TestTFS to TFS  programmatically.

I know there is a tool named TeamFoundation Administration Tool can do that, but I do not want to use it.

Comment: Check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961727/how-to-grant-read-only-access-to-all-tfs-team-projects-to-a-group-of-users/7971731#7971731

Answer (score 6):

In TFS2012, the `IGroupSecurityService` was marked obsolete and replaced with `IIdentityManagementService`.

You can use [`IIdentityManagementService.ReadIdentity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731745.aspx) along with [`IIdentityManagementService.AddMemberToApplicationGroup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iidentitymanagementservice.addmembertoapplicationgroup.aspx) to add Windows users to TFS groups, even if those Windows users are not known to TFS yet.

This is accomplished by specifying the [`ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.common.readidentityoptions.aspx) option.

Below is an example of adding a Windows user `VSALM\Barry` to the `Fabrikam Fiber Web Team` (TFS Group), in the `FabrikamFiber` Team Project, in the `http://vsalm:8080/tfs/FabrikamFiberCollection` server/collection.

You will need to add references to: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common`

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://vsalm:8080/tfs/FabrikamFiberCollection"));

            var ims = tpc.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            var tfsGroupIdentity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
                                                    "[FabrikamFiber]\\Fabrikam Fiber Web Team",
                                                    MembershipQuery.None,
                                                    ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);            

            var userIdentity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
                                                    "VSALM\\Barry",
                                                    MembershipQuery.None,
                                                    ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);

            ims.AddMemberToApplicationGroup(tfsGroupIdentity.Descriptor, userIdentity.Descriptor);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, finally following code worked

```
            NTAccount f = new NTAccount(userName);
            SecurityIdentifier s = (SecurityIdentifier)f.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            string userSid = s.ToString();
```

Namespace : `using System.Security.Principal;`

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform this operation via the TFS API, you need access to 2 levels of information.

1. The sid of the user you want to add,
2. The sid of the group you want to add the user to 
   => The code you have shown in your post will get you the id of the group you want to add the user to.

I found 2 links with sample code i think can be helpful to you,

- http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid950BA08A78C801F46B18D196597CBB40E2E2B29D.aspx
- Source code of the tfs admin tool: http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/83047#1591025

Comment: But i still have a problem that how can i get the sid of the user i want to add....  just use   Identity userIdentity = tfsSecurityService.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, userName, QueryMembership.Direct);     But i think this only work for user known to TFS...... How can i get the sid of the users that is not known to TFS... Is there something i understand in a wrong way?

Comment: Koders site is ***dead***