# Add groups and users from Active directory to TFS programatically

Tags: c#, tfs, active-directory, tfs-sdk

We can add programmatically users and groups to TFS, and add AD users/groups in TFS using administrative context for a team project. But can I add groups with users from the Active Directory to the TFS collection programatically? I'm working on the following situation: after creating a new group with users on AD, include it in TFS collection programatically.

I'm interested in a .NET C# solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583213/tfs-2013-get-all-tfs-group-including-windows-group) post:

You can use the code snippet to add windows users to TFS.

"

```
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://mytfs:8080/tfs/MyCollection"));
var identityService = collection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
var readIdentity = identityService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactory.AccountName, @"[domailName here]\" + userName, MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
```

"

Other useful posts for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed719386-925b-49a3-a7d7-5c2a147c7da2/add-ad-group-to-tfs-group-programmatically?forum=tfsadmin

[How to add users programmatically to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018374/how-to-add-users-programmatically-to-tfs)