# How can I grant access to all Team Projects for a custom group

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

I have a custom group in TFS, and I would like to grant access to this group for every team project so we don't have to do this one by one.

It seems like the developers have access via Source Control Explorer, but cannot see these projects via 'Connect to Team Project'.

Any idea what is going wrong, or what permission is missing?

We are using TFS2012 on-premise.

Comment: Hosted TFS Service, or on-Premises?

Comment: This may help, though it's from TFS2010: [How to Grant Read-Only Access to All TFS Team Projects to a Group of Users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961727/how-to-grant-read-only-access-to-all-tfs-team-projects-to-a-group-of-users)

Answer (score 1):

The [tfssecurity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd) command line tool allows us to manage permissions for TFS groups and users. We could use it in a PowerShell script to grant access to projects that already exists. However I haven't found a way to use this command at the TFS collection level in order to grant permissions for future projects.

The approach I use is based on the fact that TFS permissions are inherited unless explicitly denied.

To create an user group that will automatically access all existent projects as well as the futures ones, follow those steps:

1. Create a new security group at the project collection level. From Visual Studio you can do it from the "Team / Team Project Collection Settings/Group Membership" menu. On TFS Online you can access to "Account Settings / Security" page.
2. Add the new group as a member of the "Project Collection Administrators" group. This will grant access to all projects in the collection, including the futures ones.
3. Deny the permissions of the new group, in order to limit the administrator permissions inherited by the group. You can use an existent TFS group as template, and deny all permissions except those explicity allowed to the group which behavior you want to copy. For example, if you want to create a group with the same permissions that has the default "Project Collection Valid Users" group, you can deny all permisisons except "Create a workspace", "View build resources" and "View collection-level information"

Comment: Explicit Deny or implicit Deny (Not Set) is the default except for pre-defined roles.  So when you say "TFS Permissions are inherited unless explicitly denied" .. that's misleading.  Sure, inheritance is how you get off the ground, but the concept of least privilege is what I wanted to stress here re: the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you’ll need to give your users a log more privileges than they need to have. You can give them privileges that are similar to project collection administrators and they will have access to all projects but with elevated privileges.

It is possible do this but only for source control like you’ve already done but I’m not really sure about connecting to projects, working with workitems and such.

Comment: That's a shame.  Seems like a pretty basic use case to me.