# Visual Studio Online define user That have access to see and edit some projects in solution

Tags: c#, security, tfs, azure-devops

We have a solution that contains 11 projects in tfs online.

How to define a new user in tfs online and be sure he/she dont copy our solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Grant Read-Only Access to All TFS Team Projects to a Group of Users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961727/how-to-grant-read-only-access-to-all-tfs-team-projects-to-a-group-of-users)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to set different permissions for different projects in one solution. In the Source Control Explorer, right-click the project in the solution and click Advanced -> Security.

[image]

Then set different settings for Check In, Check Out and Read permissions for different project.

[image]