# Make everyone a reviewer of VSTS pull requests

Tags: azure-devops

We want to set up a pool code review system where any developer can see a list of all pending code review requests and pick some to review. We're using Visual Studio Team Services.

As a first step, I need to allow the entire Project Collection Valid Users group to be added as reviewer of a pull request. (Currently the field seems to accept only users who are explicit members of the project team.) The second step is to grant read-access to all projects to all collection valid users.

The latter step seems to be answered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358300/127670).

But I'm completely stuck on making everyone a pull request reviewer. Is this even possible? If so how? (I'd prefer not to rely on a third-party extension if it can be done without.)

Comment: You probably need to create a project local group "Reviewers", stick the "Account valid users" in there and then configure on a per-project basis. I suppose that while the UI may be blocking you, the API will happily allow you to pull in account global groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below steps to make everyone as reviewers for VSTS pull requests:

1. Add an account level group to add all users as members for the group

   In Security Page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_security) -> Create group -> input group name (assume it’s Engineering here) -> add all the users as members for the Engineering group.

   [image]
2. Add the account level group (Engineering group) for each projects

   In a project security page (https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_admin/_security) -> add the Engineering Group as a member for the project’s group or team.

   [image]
3. Select the project team/group (which you add Engineering group as a member) for PR reviewers in the project

   [image]
4. You can install Pull Request Dashboard extension to view the PRs clearly

   You can install [Pull Request Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard) extension, so that users can view Pull Requests in the project by different kinds of categories: Request By me, Assigned To Me and Other Open Pull Requests.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks - sorry it took me so long to respond. The above works. It's not quite as frictionless as I hoped because each project has to be configured individually. Pull Request Dashboard is nice.

Comment: Yes, it needs to config project-to-project. But it only need to config for one time each project.

Answer (score -1):

By default, nothing like everyone, you can add as many people you want as reviewer.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. I want everyone to be a reviewer without having to add individuals.